# how to access mp3 files from sd card of a mobile device

Tags: android, media-player

I am trying to make a media player app but I am not able to access the music files from my mobile devise I have take the user permission also .how can I access the mp3 files.I tried to access the media file from a file from the SD Card with file name Download.But it is not working.Is there any way to access all the mp3 files from the android device?Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private static final String SD_PATH =new String("/Download/");
private List<String> songs =new ArrayList<String>();
private MediaPlayer mp =new MediaPlayer();
class Mp3Filter implements FilenameFilter{

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
        return (filename.endsWith(".mp3"));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    updatePlaylist();
    Button button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.stop();
        }
    });

}
protected void onListItemClick(ListView list,View view,int position,long id){
    try{
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(position));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name),e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void updatePlaylist() {
   File home =new File(SD_PATH);
    if (home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length > 0) {

        for(
                File file:home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter())
                ) {
            songs.add(file.getName());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String>songlist =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.text,songs);
        setListAdapter(songlist);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not pointing to the correct sd card directory .
Your `SD_PATH` should look like -

```
String SD_PATH = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
```

This is the external storage path of Downloads folder on the sd card for the device. You can append the particular file name to this path for your purpose.

Comment: how can I access all the mp3 files?

Comment: You have to query MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI for audio files.